# How can I Make Sure No Hair Is In The Mesh?

Tags: particles, hair

I am making a leopard. I have modelled the mesh, and it is sitting in the file. I am trying to add hair to the leopard, and when adding the hair to its body, it is inside the body. How do I make sure that all of the hair is outside the mesh? What if I want it inside?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE Aphrodite. Could you add a screenshot of the hair inside the mesh? Hair is usually emitted in the normal direction of the faces.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the hair cannot get inside as the default Path render method is used. Shorten the hair as I can see it has the default length which is way too long. Make the length something like 0.1. And If you want hair **all over** your mesh, increase the hair number. If it's too low not all faces get it. Like check at the info bar how many faces your mesh has, multiply this number e.g. by 2 and input this value as the hair number. Set your Hair/face to 2 et voila.

Comment: How do I set this origin?

Comment: It's not working as I thought it would be. There is more hair on the face but some hair is still inside. Also, when I am combing it to smoothen the fur, it goes inside the mesh depsite having deflect origin on. What is the default path render?

Comment: @Aphrodite: read https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/physics/particles/particle_system_panel.html?highlight=particles

Comment: @Lucasz-40sth It doesn't help with the problem that the hair is still inside the mesh. Also, if I make the length smaller the hair still does not appear on the face when I want it to appear everywhere (I'm modelling a leopard, they have hair everywhere).

Comment: Certainly not inside their mouth, but this involves vertex groups. And see the edited answer.

Comment: I tried with 100000 hairs and there is still hair that is inside the mesh. It is not a problem with the hair number. Also when I brush it it still goes inside the mesh (I know because they were not there before the brush) even with deflect emitter set twice the length of the hair. I use Blender 2.8 if that helps, but if something works for 2.79 tell me please.